# Getting data from SQLite database error

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting a error which is really frustrating...
I want to get a title out of my database by calling this:

```
    public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_DATUM,
                    KEY_HOUR,
                    KEY_NOTE
            },
                    KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

After that I want to retrieve a String with this code:

```
Cursor c = db.getTitle(i);

System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("hour")));
```

The i is a value between 1 and 8.
When I call this I get a error that I requested the index 0, but I'm trying to get the index 2 (which is "hour").

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WHat is the value of KEY_HOUR? Is it "hour"?

Comment: @Tarun yes it's "hour".

Comment: what is the type of i is it long type?

Comment: Are you sure your cursor has items? Can you print the column names, count returned by cursor for eg c.getColumnNames(), c.getCount(). This will surely give you the clue.

Comment: @Tarun Okay, I tried a few things again. It was that the cursor was empty because I tried to get the 1 untill 8 items, which I deleted earlier. I solved it by getting all titles istead of a few in a loop. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: what is the type of rowId ? if it's string you should put it inside ''. also replace if(c != null) with if(c != null && !c.isAfterLast()) to make sure that you're actually fetching something!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the items out of the database which I already deleted earlier. I requested a item with id 1, which didn't existed anymore. I solved it by getting all the data of my database.